# Why Swift JSONDecodable fails?

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization, decodable

I try to decode the errors from HTTP request using `JSONDecodable` but it fails.

I have created a custom class and extended with `Decodable`.

```
class CustomError: Decodable {

    // Properties
    var errors: [String: [String:String]]?
    var message: String?
}
```

And using the following line to decode which returns `nil`:

```
let jsonError = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CustomError.self, from: data!)
```

But I get the following resulting using `JSONSerialization`:

```
let jsonError = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
```

**Result:**

```
Optional({
    errors =     {
        email =         (
            "The email has already been taken."
        );
    };
    message = "The given data was invalid.";
})
```

Any reason why the `Decodable` doesn't work?

Comment: If you used a regular `try` instead of `try?`, then you could catch the error and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this because you have the array of values(email) in errors:

```
var errors: [String: [String]]?
```